# how to convert part of json response to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have JSON response that looks like this

```
{"values": 
 [
        {
            "type": "NAME",
            "match": "EXACT",
            more properties here
        },
        {
            "type": "LASTNAME",
            "match": "AMBIG",
            more properties here
        }
] }
```

how can I convert this to javascript map that contains only type and match properties?

For example

```
{
 'NAME' : 'EXACT' ,
 'LASTNAME' : 'AMBIG' 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/u9ycpLgs/

Looping through test.values and creating a new object where the value of the type is the new key and the value of the match is the new value.

```
var test = {
    "values": [{
        "type": "NAME",
            "match": "EXACT"
    }, {
        "type": "LASTNAME",
            "match": "AMBIG"
    }]
};

keyValuePairs = {};

test.values.forEach(function (item) {
    keyValuePairs[item.type] = item.match;
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(keyValuePairs));

/*
 Output:

  {"NAME":"EXACT","LASTNAME":"AMBIG"}
*/
```

Comment: You can convert your answer into a one-liner using `reduce`. `hashMap = test.values.reduce(function(accumulator, item) {
      return accumulator[item.type] = item.match;
    }, {})`

Comment: @Pete, good call. Post that as an answer and I'll vote for it!